# Why not SSL enable Apache with own CA?

Tags: ssl, certificate, authority

I purchased a domain name.  I set up a website that is deployed on Apache, that is accessible at my domain, currently on http protocol "port 80".  I now want to configure this Apache server for SSL.  I'm evaluating the below 2 options.

Option #1: I create the "Certificate Signing Request" (CSR), then while acting as the CA, I create the certificate based on the CSR, I then configure Apache to be running on port 443, with the certificate I created.

Option #2: I create the CSR, I submit my CSR to a widely known CA like Symantec to get a certificate.  I then configure Apache to be running on port 443, with the certificate provided by Symantec.

What are the downfalls to option #1?

From an end-user perspective "someone accessing my site", what indications would they have that I used option #1?

Is it correct to assume, with option #1, that I couldn't get end-users accessing my site to get a green bar menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With option 1 the end user has no confidence they are not being spoofed.  Because you are acting as your own CA the end user has to make a decision about whether to trust you.  If they do - they may well be trusting someone who has intercepted your request and used their own certificate.

With option 2 the user is trusting the CA that provided your certificate and can be more confident that no man-in-the-middle attack is taking place.

For some purposes your own self-signed cert can be fine.  Not for any real ecommerce though.

Comment: What indication is the end-user getting that I'm not using a highly recognized CA?  For an advanced user, they will likely know to click the key icon at the left of the browser URL bar To see this CA info...  But for typical/most users, would they be made aware in any way?

Comment: They will not trust your certificate by default so they will get an untrusted certificate notification.  Only if they trust the signing certificate is that notification avoid.  Most CAs trace their certs back to a cert that is trusted by a browser automatically.

Comment: Some servers now make it very clear that the certificate is not trusted - often blocking the page until you allow it.

Comment: I was thinking that the untrusted certificate notification would be a reason.  Thank you for the response.